# Anti-aliased rasterization of vectors in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, polygon, rasterization

I have some polygons that I want to rasterize, but in a fairly low-resolution grid (cell size 250x250m). The raster values of the area inside the polygons should normally have the same value (100), but most of the polygons are fairly small (say max 50 m wide), which means that right now they often don't even show up in the final raster (using gdal:rasterize or saga:rasterize). What I would have liked is for the raster value to have been interpolated, in the sense that the final pixel value would have been lower than 100 (say 30) but still present in the output raster. Is there any stock algorithm in QGIS capable of this?

I guess that another way would be to first do a much higher-resolution bi-valued rasterization, and then downsample the resulting raster with an algorithm that hopefully handles this. This would probably be slower and require more memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: [see here for a model](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421142/88814) to automatically run this workflow.

1. Create a vector grid with the same extent and resolution as the raster you intend to create.
2. Calculate the percentage (area) each grid cell intersects with the polygons to be rasterized - see screenshot 1. Use filed calculator to create a new field with this value. To calculate the percentage, you can use this expression (replace `poly` with the name of your polygon layer):

```
    area (
        intersection (
            $geometry,
            collect_geometries(
                overlay_intersects( 
                    'poly',
                    $geometry
                )
            )
        )
    )
    /area ($geometry) * 100
```

3. Use this percentage value for the raster value to be created: from 100 (complete interesection) to 0 (no intersection at all) wit in-between values based on intersection percentage, see screenshot 2.
   For rasterize, use `Menu Raster / Conversion / Rasterize (vector to raster)` - see screenshot below for settings: set the grid and the attribute field with the calculated percentage (named `pixelval` in my case) is input and set `Output raster size units` to the same size as your grid and `Output size` to the extent of your grid-layer (or your polygon-layer, because the extent of the grid should be the same as the polygon, see step 1). Be aware: the screenshot shows a layer in `EPSG:3857`, this normally is not ideal for processing, just due to creation of a fast test dataset for visualization.

*Screenshot 1: Polygons in yellow, grid in blue. The grid-cells are labeled (for visualization purpose) with the expression from above + a round() function:*
[image]

*Screenshot 2: And that's how the final raster looks like:*

[image]

*Screenshot 3: setting of the rasterize dialog:*
[image]

**Edit/addition**

I created a model for this workflow that [can be downloaded here](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/siR7UAve9j9MTm1) (update: [improved version here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421142/88814)). You have to adapt the values and make sure that the project CRS is the same as the CRS of the input polygon layer you load. The expression from step 2 refers to the layer named `polygon`, so the input layer should be named like this.

*Screenshot of the model:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a very exact (and may I say "GIS-esque") way of solving it (whereas my idea was more of an image processing-approach). Will try it out!

Comment: Indeed, the solution is "GIS-esque", nicely sayed ;-) It depends of course for what you need it, but I suppose using a GIS (instead on an image processing software), makes sense if you apply space aware operations and that's why you opted for it.

Comment: In the expression, be sure to replace `'poly'` with the name of your polygon layer.

Comment: Sure did, worked nicely!
Any tips on specific algorithm to use for the rasterization (step 3)? I am quite new to QGIS.

Comment: Update my answer for your question about rasterize

Comment: Thank you. Now I am aware of the field calculator! :) I guess this is the accepted answer then since my aims is to codify the whole algorithm in a plugin (or graphical model), and QGIS doesn't seem to expose any raster downsampling algorithm to scripts (although the functionality is certainly there since the "Align rasters"-tool features several choices of downsampling algorithms.

Comment: I am trying to implement this as a graphical model. Are you aware of any reliable way of referencing the 'poly' layer in step 2 above as the output from another algorithm in the model (or failing that, at least a model input)?

Comment: Creating a model is one thing (see updated answer), adapting the expression of step 2 to changing input layer names is something else. I guess it should be possible using the `Pre-caluculated value` entry, where you can get a variable named after your model input, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD7qP.png - However, I did not found the correct syntax to adapt the expression accordingly: `... overlay_intersects(@loadpolygonlayer,$geometry) ...` did not work. Maybe worth asking a new question here?

Comment: Added as a question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/397685/88814

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is a different topic. I just seized on the opportunity to tap your expertise☺️. The linked question indeed gives some guidance, but I may need to refactor my model to several models it seems.