# Splitting population between overlapping polygon features

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, splitting, population

I have a quadratic grid with a different population in each square as *the first layer* and I have polygons that I made with the ORS Plugin as *the second layer*.

In [my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409064/counting-population-within-polygons/409072#409072), I got some good help to calculate the population that each polygon covers in each square.

However, I now need to take into consideration that polygons *overlap in some squares*, and then **I need to divide the population** in those areas between the polygons. I am fine with assuming that the population is evenly distributed in each square, and I want to divide the population evenly among the polygons that overlap.

Please keep in mind that I may have several polygons overlapping. I also have many polygons, about 4.000, and squares, several millions.

**OBS:**

`"ID"`    | The polygons IDs
`"Id-2"`  | Squares in the grid’s IDs
`"POP-2"` | The population in each Square

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there are two polygon layers `'grid_test'` (red) and `'grid_test2'` (green) respectively, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to achieve the result, i.e. to to calculate the population that each polygon in `'grid_test'` covers in each polygon in `'grid_test2'`.

```sql
SELECT a.*, sum(b."popul"*st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry))/st_area(b.geometry)) AS res
FROM "grid_test" AS a
LEFT JOIN "grid_test2" AS b ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
GROUP BY a.id
```

The output Virtual Layer will look like as following

[image: output]

*Note:* Since we are talking about population, the application of the [round()](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-round/) function can make sense i.e. `round(sum(b."popul"*st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry))/st_area(b.geometry)))`

---

**References:**

- [Transferring flows (connections + values) between polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317599/transferring-flows-connections-values-between-polygons)
- [Flow data distribution within features of overlapping layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327067/flow-data-distribution-within-features-of-overlapping-layers)
- [Creating relations many to one in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407639/creating-relations-many-to-one-in-qgis)
- [Calculating point layer values within polygon features in QGIS 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305165/calculating-point-layer-values-within-polygon-features-in-qgis-2)